# Group row data from multiple multidimensional arrays by date column and sum another column within each group

Tags: php, arrays, merge, sum, grouping

I need to merge and group the data from 3 multidimensional arrays by a shared date column.  Within these groups, I want to sum the Unit column values so that I have a single 2d array with rows containing unique dates and total units.

```
$array1 = [
    [
        "sales" => [
            ["Date" => "2014-04-01", "Units" => 1],
            ["Date" => "2014-04-02", "Units" => 7]
        ]
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    [
        "sales" => [
            ["Date" => "2014-04-01", "Units" => 3],
            ["Date" => "2014-04-02", "Units" => 2]
        ]
    ]
];

$array3 = [
    [
        "sales" => [
            ["Date" => "2014-04-01", "Units" => 0],
            ["Date" => "2014-04-02", "Units" => 5]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Desired output::

```
[
    ['Date' => '2014-04-01', 'Units' => 4],
    ['Date' => '2014-04-02', 'Units' => 14],
]
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array1 = array("orange", "banana");
$array2 = array("ab", "ba");
$array3 = array("cd", "ef");
array_push($array1,$array2 , $array3);
print_r($array1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr1=array(
'Date' => '2014-04-02'
 'Units' => 5
    );
$arr2=array(
'Date' => '2014-04-02'
 'Units' => 5
    );
$arr3=array(
'Date' => '2014-04-02'
 'Units' => 5
    );

$arr['sales'][0]=$arr1;
  $arr['sales'][1]=$arr2;
  $arr['sales'][2]=$arr3;
$data[]=$arr;

print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the arrays as you mention, a way to do it is the following:

```
<?php 

$first =  array ();
$first[0] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-01",  "Units" => 1 );
$first[1] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-02",  "Units" => 7 );
$first[2] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-03",  "Units" => 5 );
$first[3] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-04",  "Units" => 1 );



echo "<pre>";
print_r ($first);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr>";

$second =  array ();
$second[0] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-01",  "Units" => 3 );
$second[1] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-02",  "Units" => 2 );
$second[2] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-03",  "Units" => 5 );
$second[3] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-04",  "Units" => 2 );

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($second);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr>";

$third =  array ();
$third[0] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-01",  "Units" => 0 );
$third[1] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-02",  "Units" => 5 );
$third[2] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-03",  "Units" => 5 );
$third[3] =  array ( "Date" => "2014-04-04",  "Units" => 4 );

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($third);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr>The total is: ";



$total = array();

foreach ($first as $key=>$day) {
    $total[$key]=array("Date" => "2014-04-02",  "Units" => ($first[$key]["Units"]  +$second[$key]["Units"]  +$third[$key]["Units"]) );

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($total);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr>";
```

But this works only if the key for each date is the same. (Aka, 0 always corresponds to 2014-04-01 ). 
If I had to work with that, I would probably look one step before, to how those arrays get created, and I would use the date, as the key

Answer (score 0):

Merge the relevant subsets from each array into a single array so that all data can be iterated in a single loop.

While looping, if a date value is encountered for the first time, save the whole row as a reference variable and push that reference into the result array. If a date value is encountered again, access only Units value and add it to the reference's Unit value.

Using references in this way avoids needing to call `array_values()` after looping to remove temporary keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LAd3O))

```
$result = [];
foreach (array_merge($a[0]['sales'], $b[0]['sales'], $c[0]['sales']) as $row) {
    if (!isset($ref[$row['Date']])) {
        $ref[$row['Date']] = $row;
        $result[] =& $ref[$row['Date']];
    } else {
        $ref[$row['Date']]['Units'] += $row['Units'];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```